# Error when starting project from command line

Tags: react-native-fbsdk

I installed the package [using npm](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk#1-install-the-library) I then followed [these instructions (french)](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/755#issuecomment-648729664) to configure it for iOS. But I can't run the app using `npx react-native run-ios`, it gives me this error:

```sh
xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:
    because no versions of facebook-ios-sdk match the 
    requirement 7.0.2..<8.0.0 and root depends on 
    facebook-ios-sdk 7.0.2..<8.0.0, version solving failed.
```

I tried to reinstall `react-native-fbsdk` and also installing pods again:

```sh
$ cd ios
$ rm Podfile.lock
$ pod repo update
$ pod install 

Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBApp: [RNFB] Core Configuration
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `XXX`: RNCMaskedView, RNFBApp, RNFBAuth, RNGestureHandler, RNGoogleSignin, RNReanimated, RNScreens, RNVectorIcons, react-native-fbsdk, react-native-get-random-values, react-native-safe-area-context, and react-native-webview
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Downloading dependencies
Installing FBSDKCoreKit 7.1.1 (was 7.0.1 and source changed to `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` from `trunk`)
Installing FBSDKLoginKit 7.1.1 (was 7.0.1 and source changed to `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` from `trunk`)
Installing FBSDKShareKit 7.1.1 (was 7.0.1 and source changed to `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` from `trunk`)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 41 dependencies from the Podfile and 59 total pods installed.
```

On the other hand I have no issue running it from xcode (even though the error still show up).

My npm environment is the following:

```
{
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^2.0.0",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea what's going on with the installation as proposed in the documentation. But we solved the problem in Xcode by **updating facebook-ios-sdk**:
`file` > `Swift packages` > `Update to latest package versions`.

After running this, facebook-ios-sdk version appears in Xcode (for us it was **7.1.1**). And then the error goes away.